# referencing function from setInterval using Javascript

Tags: javascript

When I try and run the add function it gives `TypeError: this.add is not a function`

```
function Timer(){
    this.t; 
    this.count = 0;

    this.start = function(){
        this.t = setInterval(function () {this.add()}, 1000);
    }
    this.add = function(){
        this.count++;
        console.log(this.count);
    }
}

function startTimer(){
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.start();
}
```

How am I able to access this.add function in that instance?

Comment: I'm reluctant to link to that other QA as it's full of answers which aren't the best one today. The accepted one, especially, wouldn't really help OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution would be to create a variable to hold `this` but a simpler one is to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
this.t = setInterval(this.add.bind(this), 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `this` inside your anonymous function get wrong context. You need to `bind` that function to your original context:

```
this.t = setInterval(function () {this.add()}.bind(this), 1000);
```

Or keep reference to your context inside some variable:

```
function Timer(){
    this.t; 
    this.count = 0;

    this.start = function(){
        var self = this;
        this.t = setInterval(function () {self.add()}, 1000);
    } 
...
```

Comment: Don't you think there's a simpler solution ? ;)

Comment: I think your solution is simpler of course, but it depends on context and what OP will need in final result ;)